# Safe ways to get reimbursement (North America)?

Tags: security, reimbursement

Let's say that I'm getting reimbursed for an out of pocket expense by a company.
Due to [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15218/is-it-safe-to-give-out-ones-bank-account-number?newreg=49e41b86fc74423589d7c89ca5d7c609) post I'm concerned about giving out my account number. even if I trust the company - the account number can leak. If reimbursement using acount number happens with multiple companies - that risk rises.

What would be the safest ways to get such reimbursement remotely?

Comment: You could have them write and mail a check. It's worked for many, many years; it still works.

Comment: @keshlam I've not heard of an arbitrary company doing a direct bank transfer for an expense reimbursement so a check is probably the most logical way to handle it.  If the OP is concerned about his or her employer having his/her account number, then that's a different level of tinfoil hat wearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it an official Answer: If you aren't willing to give them any of your own banking information, have them write you a check.