# I am an EU resident being contacted about stock I own in a defunct company by a supposedly US based lawyer, is this a scam?

Tags: scams, law, bankruptcy, corporate-acquisition

I am based in the EU, so I have very little knowledge of how the US legal system works.

I have been contacted by a "law firm" in the US about a financial issue: a company in which I own a small amount of shares went bankrupt several years ago, and apparently they are in liquidation and being bought by another company. I had completely written off this investment until this law firm contacted me out of the blue a couple of days ago, and now I am hesitating since:

1. They are offering immediate payout
2. They are sending me a PSA (Payment Settlement Agreement And Mutual Releases) / PSPA (Private Stock Purchase And Escrow Agreement) for me to sign. I do not know what those are.
3. They are asking for a bank account for the payment.

This is the full email text (redacted for anonymity):

> Please find attached the documents pertaining to the investment that
>   you made in XXX Investment currently known as XXIT (XXX
>   XXX Investment Trust) several years ago.
>
> You, as all other shareholders, have the legal right to sell your
>   position to our client, who is at this point in time the only buyer,
>   he already has 51% control of of the common shares, however, it is his
>   intention to acquire at least 75% of the outstanding shares to gain
>   complete control over the assets of the company. The remaining 25%
>   would be immediately absorbed by the new owner and have no financial
>   value whatsoever to the existing shareholder. Under US law this is
>   perfectly legal and a commonly used practice of acquiring full control
>   through the purchase of a majority interest.
>
> The company no longer  trades on any stock market  as it is in
>   receivership. There is no administrative board to contact, and it
>   doesn't even have a valid corporate ID any more, therefore research
>   options are very limited,as you can imagine.
>
> Upon receipt of  your signed documentation, I will put you in the
>   payout list. This is a first come first served situation ,so obviously
>   time is of the essence.

Does this sound legitimate? The wording does, but I have been checking a bit online, and I am suspicious:

1. The website could be a simple stock template.
2. The whois of the website of the law firm refers to a registrar in Panama (edit: this seems due to `WhoisGuard Protected`). It has been registered very recently: `Creation Date: 2017-11-13`
3. I can not find the law firm in any registry - but I do not know where to look, to be honest.
4. The law firm is not to be found in Google Maps, nor in Google itself. It does appear in Bing though.
5. They are trying to get this done quickly.

So I tend to think that this is a scam, but I would like to understand how this is supposed to work.

1. In case I provide my bank account number (IBAN number in the EU), how will they be able to abuse this? I will simply cancel any suspecting charge in my account.
2. What are they trying to do with me signing the PSPA / PSA documents?

What other research could I perform to verify the authenticity of this? Any other advice?

### Edit

Email signature:

> Burke Corporate Law
>
> 800 N Glebe Rd, Arlington, VA 22203 United States Phone: 1 (571) 480
>   6959 www.burkecorporatelaw.com

Comment: Good question.  However, might be better asked on Law.SE.

Comment: Is it possible to give out the name of the company you invested in. This will help verify the current status of the company. If it is indeed in bankruptcy and is this being restructured and who is interested in buying this.

Comment: @Dheer The original company was "Greenwood Investment", and the buyer seems to be Natural Resources Investment Trust. The former I know, since I was an investor, but the latter is unkown to me, and I have not yet researched it. But for me the interesting party is the law firm: who are they, where are they based, do they really exist, what do they want, is it legitimate?

Comment: Presumably your EU country has an embassy in Washington, DC (which is on the border between Virginia and Maryland).  Have you tried asking them to verify legitimacy of the law firm?

Comment: You can just go right ahead and put the "website" URL on here man, no negative in that.

Comment: Note that as well as the 10-year-old style writing, every single thing it says in the email (25% ! etc) is just wholly ridiculous and nonsensical.

Comment: Tell them to snail mail the documents to your address of record.  If they actually send them to you, that *might* indicate validity.

Comment: No official action relating to securities should be contracting you directly.  I have been through a couple similar situations to the one you describe, and not once have I received an email at my private address- ALL correspondence is directed at my broker, who then passes along legitimate documentation to me.  Assuming you bought the shares through a brokerage, what does that broker know about ongoing legal proceedings?  I would guess nothing, because the information isn't legitimate.

Comment: @Derek_6424246 I made the investment directly, long time ago.

Comment: @Derek_6424246: That assumes you HAVE a broker.  I had a somewhat similar situation: shares of a former employer bought through an ESOP, employer was bought out by another company (Berkshire Hathaway, as it happens), they contacted me directly.  Of course the difference was that the former employer was an operating & profitable company, not bankrupt.

Comment: _The company no longer trades on any stock market as it is in receivership._ So you don't own anything.

Comment: @AbraCadaver is that so? Couldn't a company in liquidation have a residual value? After debt and corporate restructuring, that company could be profitable again ...

Comment: have you asked the SEC they should know what happened to the firm

Comment: @AbraCadaver Many companies are not traded publicly, ie on the stock market, but they do sell shares privately.  Often employee owned companies sell stock to the employees and it is only available to them, thus they are not traded on a market.

Comment: I'm really interested in the question, how would you "report" something like this?  i.e., would OP call "the FBI" or ??   Should the Wordpress hosting company be told they are hosting a potentially dangerous scam?  What if the villains in question are actually physically dangerous - not merely the usual bank account scrapers etc??  Who do ya call?

Comment: We've had this happen multiple times with one company my dad once invested in. Google street view showed... a laundry in boston where their address was.

Comment: There's one part of the wording that sounds seriously sketchy: "Yes this is legal". Unnecessary and unasked for assertions are always cause for concern, in my experience.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, as to "The company no longer trades on any stock market as it is in receivership."...that is what that email says. The email could be a scam and that statement should not be accepted at the face value.

Comment: BTW I wonder if they put up their website in a rush. The site burkecorporatelaw.com has some obvious misspellings near the bottom half of the page. Like "HAPPY CLINETS" (instead of CLIENTS) and "RECOVERD" (instead of RECOVERED).

Comment: if you want to report them you could maybe report them to SEC (U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission) through their "Submit a Tip" button on this page: www.sec.gov/tcr

Comment: I just Googled their tag line, and [Seth Cohen LLC](https://www.scamwarners.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=142496), another scam, it seems, used the same line.

Comment: In addition to the research you already did, I recommend having a look at archive.org wayback machine for that domain. There you can then figure out it has a robots.txt that disallows everything. Who in their right mind wants to stay hidden from search machines with their business website?

Comment: fascinating report, @JourneymanGeek - it seems to be a "system" then.

Comment: `situation ,so ob` -- I'd presume scam just from that typo. (`", "` vs `" ,"`)

Comment: On the plus side, you can 'get free consulation!' from this firm :) Great website.

Comment: *so obviously time is of the essence* is the only line I need to see. That's copypasta scam material.

Comment: Has there ever been a "Is this a scam?" question on stackexchange which wasn't a scam?

Comment: The generally informal tone of the letter is also suspicious.

Comment: @Brythan "Have you tried asking [your country's embassy] to verify legitimacy of the law firm?" That's not even close to what embassies are for.

Comment: I am not aware of any provision under US law where a majority (or supermajority) stock holder can simply cancel everybody else's stock.  Bankruptcy of a firm could cancel _all_ stock, but I don't think even chapter 7 can cancel _some_ of the stock.

Comment: Very unusual that a reverse lookup on the phone number doesn't show anything connected with the purported firm. Also, it would be very unusual for a US firm to use the 24 hour clock for contact times.

Comment: @x457812: That didn't make the OP suspicious so unless they correct the assumption, it seems that it was traded.

Comment: @cornbread: I know this.  I was making an assumption _The company no longer trades on any stock market_

Comment: @dangonfast: In the event that a publicly listed company declares bankruptcy, the company's shareholders may be entitled to a portion of the liquidated assets, depending on which shares they hold and how much liquid assets are left over. However, the stock itself will become worthless, leaving shareholders unable to sell their defunct shares.

Comment: Fun fact: the numerous red flags all over this thing are not mistakes made by the scammers; they are deliberate.  **They are attempting to weed out people who notice red flags**.  You only want the *most* gullible people to be victims of your scam because they are the highest reward for the lowest risk.

Comment: My brain's Bayesian filter immediately identifies this as run of the mill spam.

Comment: See this answer, they can access your funds in Germany with IBAN and copied signature. https://money.stackexchange.com/a/15237/63585

Comment: When you originally bought/acquired the shares, did you use / register the email address that you have now been contacted on? If you _didn't_ give the original company an email address (or used a different one), then how did they get your current email address?

Comment: The "Contact us" form does not send anything to them !!!

Comment: Have you left a callback number or talked to someone yet?  Scammers are easy to spot on the phone.  Just start swearing at them and insulting them calling them scammers. Most scammers just hang up or start saying insults back.  The fact that you actually owned the stock they inquired about means you should at least inquire more into it.  Tell them they can have it for free.

Comment: Is the new of bankrupted company mentioned exactly and fully? Is there any information that they know you are shareholder? Does the lawer know your full name or only the email and "sir/Mr."?

Comment: You had me until `I have been contacted by a "`...

Comment: I enjoyed James Veitch's videos on YouTube in which he contacts scammers and strings them along.  May be useful to give familiarity with the 'flavor' or 'odor' of a scam.

Answer (score 177):

A bit of detective work.

- The website lists no names for the firm. Any business, doctor, lawyer, etc, is at least going to tell you who the main partners are.
- The site itself looks like a generic framework with literally no content, just placeholders. A web designer's first pass for a client. But not a real site.
- The [website for the building](http://www.800northgleberd.info/main.cfm?pid=yourneighborhood&img=bservices&DBType=Business%20Services&sid=neighborhood&CFID=3109537&CFTOKEN=84727145) at that address doesn't list them as a tenant.
- Calling the phone number for the law firm gets a generic leave a message recording. Doesn't even mention firm name.
- A [Whois search](https://www.whois.com/whois/burkecorporatelaw.com) on the domain name shows the contact info is hidden, thru a Panama address.

Any one of these is cause for concern (did someone erase the correct outgoing voice mail greeting? Did the web guy choose "private?"), but the combination of all 5? Scam.

Comment: Yes, looks like. They sure do know a lot about my past investments. That and not understanding how the scam works is what makes me doubt. I had another chat with a "senior partner" who got very confrontational as soon as I started asking questions. He told me that as soon as they open my case (basically as soon as I start signing papers) they will put me in touch with the New York regulator. He also told me their customer is Chinese, based in Shanghai? And that they could put me in touch with them ...

Comment: They stress all the time "under US law blah-blah". I told them I want to get information about the customer and the Law firm *before* I signed anything. They told me to list my questions and that they will reply. I have just emailed them what I want to know, let'see what / whether they reply.

Comment: Thanks for the productive research. I do not know how you the the list of tenants in the building, though ...

Comment: @dangonfast : Yes, I couldn't see a list of tenants from the quoted website either. :-)

Comment: The web page allowed a search for local businesses, why wouldn't a Law Firm **in** that building be listed? The listed lawyers are from up the street.

Comment: Also note that overwhelmingly, the web site looks like a child wrote it, who had seen some random legal phrases in another language.  @dangonfast, note that legal firms always **aggressively highlight the actual partners and senior staff**.  Do you know whatI mean?  Like at a doctor's or dentist's office, it always shows the "actual professionals", do you know what I mean?  And indeed all of those individual senior people will have extensive, real, google profiles.

Comment: @Fattie - didn't my first bullet point cover that?

Comment: quite right, @JoeTaxpayer, just drawing the OP's attention to that and adding more details.   Indeed, because of the nature of the legal profession, nobody is easier to google than legal professionals - you can then google the entire career and news history of each senior staff member mentioned.  The website is a total non-starter.  Funny though!

Comment: I hope we saved the OP from losing more money, but sad how many will fall for this scam.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer you definitely helped my in pausing a bit and rethinking the whole thing. I will try to collect all information before proceeding any further. Since the whole thing seems a scam, they will probably not reply to my requests, so everything will finish here. In that case, I would like to report them, but since I do not know who they are or where they are based, this could prove extremely difficult.

Comment: You mention "the combination of all 4", but there are 5 points listed.  I suspect this answer is a scam =P

Comment: Fixed! I added a 5th, but didn’t update count. I’ll probably find a sixth one later today. LOL

Comment: The hard-sell, time-sensitive bit at the end is another tip-off. `This is a first come first served situation ,so obviously time is of the essence.`

Comment: Exactly. More signs of scam you might want to add: (1) OP needs to hurry to satisfy the greed for (2) free money, and (3) mistakes in comma-space sequence, like `...first served situation ,so obviously...`

Comment: hey @JoeTaxpayer "who ya gonna call?" in a situation like this - notice my comment at the end under the Q ...  what do you reckon?  Who would you call in the US for something like this?

Comment: "I hope we saved the OP from losing more money, but sad how many will fall for this scam." indeed, the more I think about it, imagine if this was something that leads to actual "physical confrontation" of some type (who knows? .. ranging from housebreaking, to much worse, kidnapping, who knows).  {Random idea, apart from anything else it would be great to have full address, employment, insurance information on folks with a high net worth, who have things like antiques and .. VHS players .. laying around their homes, you know?}  Horrible.

Comment: @Fattie - I don't know who to call. The web site host is likely to expect a warrant, i.e. they are not going to just give out information on who owns a domain without the court forcing them. We have a legal stack, this thread is getting away from personal finance.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer looking at their website, the phone number at the bottom of the homepage is a different number altogether. It also says that their office hours are 24/7, but on the contact page, it lists actual working hours - more red flags that the website has just been thrown together. Also, a search on [SEC website](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html) for "Burke Corporate Law" doesn't list any companies (although I don't know if all companies are listed on that site, as I'm unfamiliar with how it works in the US).

Comment: Maybe spelling errors should be added. Such as `get free
consulation!`

Comment: @Lamak They probably meant, "free consolation", after you lose all your money. :-)

Comment: Related: [Squeeze-out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze-out)

Comment: @crazyloonybin: SEC only has jurisdiction over publicly owned/traded companies, and law firms aren't public (or at least most aren't). OTOH [the Virginia bar](http://member.vsb.org/attsearch/search.aspx) shows three Burkes in Arlington, none of them at that address or phone.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 ahh ok, makes sense. I'm used to the UK Companies House website which lists all private companies. Thanks for clarifying! :)

Comment: Also of note:  The phone number listed is an exchange in Washington, Virginia, which is a small town outside the DC metro area that houses Arlington.

Comment: @Fattie FWIW, you can get a [link](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/91024#comment160566_91024) to a comment by clicking on the date (or right-clicking).

Answer (score 45):

Purely FWIW, "Does this sound legitimate?"

> The company no longer trades on any stock market as it is in receivership. There is no administrative board to contact, and it doesn't even have a valid corporate ID any more, therefore research options are very limited,as you can imagine.
>
> Upon receipt of your signed documentation, I will put you in the payout list. This is a first come first served situation ,so obviously time is of the essence.

No, it's just an everyday internet scam of some sort.

It sounds like a foreign speaker pasted it together from found phrases, "trying to sound important." The concepts mentioned in the emails (the "25% !" etc) are completely nonsensical.

> What other research could I perform to verify the authenticity of this?

1. **Just phone them**.  Couldn't be easier. Street-view the building and phone at different times to check they are a real business with secretaries, etc.
2. The key is this - web sites of legal practices big and small ***absolutely always list all the partners*** and major staff.  Then, each of those people will have a **very strong** profile in the information sphere, ranging from huge numbers of local (or bigger) news articles to endless academic mentions, legal mentions, etc. - it's the very nature of being in the legal profession.

Regarding the interesting question the OP asks of *what in particular* the scammers are up to, unfortunately IDK.

## Note ...

In a comment @JourneymanGeek reports..

> We've had this happen multiple times with one company my dad once invested in.

So there has to be "something going on" with this particular type of scam.  Unfortunately IDK what the scam is.

Comment: The first contact was by phone: they called me

Comment: The English looks fine to me, at least in the part you've quoted.

Comment: I phoned them. Generic answering machine.

Comment: @PeterK. - I'm inclined to agree with "The English and grammar is totally unprofessional." There are weird spacing issues, the use of "I" has no place here, and the word choice is very colloquial. Definitely not written by an attorney.

Comment: @TTT I agree that the use of "I" is odd for an attorney's letter.

Comment: @PeterK. - actually, perhaps instead of "English grammar" (which isn't actually that bad), "word choice" would have been a more accurate statement. I just edited to indicate that.

Comment: @TTT Yes, that's better.

Comment: Fattie, not at all. Which part do you find problematic?

Comment: Hi PK - it does not even sound vaguely like business English. it's a collection of "overheard" phrases that would never be used in the context.  Cheers for now.

Comment: Your advice of "screen them using the info *they* provided" will fail if the scammer is at all competent.   The mailing address will be of the law firm they pretend to be, so Google Street View will check out.  The phone number will be a virtual number and will be answered as the law firm.  You **must *presume*** all provided information is false in the worst way possible.

Comment: @harper pretty sure they can not use the name of a real law firm, or they will loose most leads to said law firm: the first thing I tried to do was to locate the (fake) law firm, without success, adding a lot of confusion.

Comment: And fattie, regarding english proficieny: they are all native speakers, and as far as I can tell (I am not native speaker) they are educated and articulated.

Comment: hi @Harper, they're not "pretending to be" some real law firm; it's just made-up.  you can almost instantly tell if a fake spam law firm is a real law firm or not, particularly from point "2".   only online casinos ;) have a higher internet profile than attorneys:

Comment: hi @dangonfast, fascinating, you mean on the phone they sounded like native speakers?  (To me, and as others said, as a native speaker, writer, and frequent dealer-with-legal-folks, the *web site* is just ridiculous, it sounds like a 10-yr old wrote it.)  That's really interesting if they apparently have "local-American" phone ... accomplices, team members or whatever.  You know, I'd call them up (as gutsy Joe did) but, often these things are ***less harmless than they may appear***, you know?  You know, I wonder if you should actually contact the FBI or similar?? IDK.

Comment: @fattie Definitely native, at least three people. I would say US accent - my english does not allow me to further narrow the accent. Even the email text sounds legitimate enough to my non-native ears :)

Comment: fascinating, @dangonfast.  You know, really ........... ***I would have nothing more to do with them***.  Be polite, call it a day, don't do anything that could piss them off you know?   *You never know*.  An abundance of caution is never a bad thing.  You have *utterly nothing* to gain here.

Answer (score 38):

Definitely a scam. Some warning signs in the email:

> Please find attached the documents pertaining to the investment that you made in XXX Investment currently known as XXIT (XXX XXX Investment Trust) several years ago.

Legal letters are usually very precise in their wording. I would expect a real lawyer to specify exactly *which* documents are attached. Not a red flag in itself, but combined with other issues below, it smells bad. Ditto for that vague "several years ago".

> You, as all other shareholders, have the legal right to sell your position to our client, **who is at this point in time the only buyer**,

Pressure tactic: "if you don't take this offer you'll lose out".

> he already has 51% control **of of** the common shares,

Even the browser I'm using to type this answer is smart enough to highlight "of of" as an error. It would be unusual to see this kind of mistake in a professionally-written lawyer's letter.

> however, it is his intention to acquire at least 75% of the outstanding shares to gain complete control over the assets of the company. The remaining 25% would be immediately absorbed by the new owner and have no financial value whatsoever to the existing shareholder.

Pressure tactic again: "if you don't take this offer, you'll lose your shares". I'm not a lawyer, but it seems *exceedingly* unlikely that any such rule would exist. Who would ever invest less than a 25% stake in a company if it was possible for the other 75% to eradicate their share without recompense?

Googling on "shares 75% ownership" finds nothing relevant.

> Under US law this is perfectly legal and a commonly used practice of acquiring full control through the purchase of a majority interest.

Again, suspiciously vague. No mention of which US law they're talking about. If this letter was genuine, it would be in their interests to mention the law they're invoking (e.g. a specific cite to Federal or State legal codes, or at least the legal terminology related to this claim) so you could look it up and confirm that they're telling the truth.

They don't want you checking their claims. That's a big red flag.

> The company no longer trades on any stock market as it is in receivership. There is no administrative board to contact, and it doesn't even have a valid corporate ID any more, therefore research options are very **limited,as** you can imagine.

Sloppy writing again. Repetition of "you have no other options".

> Upon receipt of your signed documentation, I will put you in the payout list.

Pretty sure "payout list" is not a legal term.

> This is a first come first served situation **,so** obviously time is of the essence.

More sloppy writing, more pressure to give a fast response without thinking it over. All hallmarks of a scam.

Some other considerations:

Scammers love to go after people who've already lost money (as you have in this case) because they understand that people hate to lose and will often jump at an opportunity to get their money back.

With a few shares in a defunct company, your investment is very unlikely to be worth more than a few dollars, maximum. It would cost far more than that to hire a real lawyer for the communication you've already had.

The only real question here is - what kind of scam? My first guess would be advance fee fraud. But regardless of what the game is, your best option is to stay well away. Even if you've decided not to give them your bank details, continuing contact risks giving them the impression that you're gullible enough to be worth a second try, and in a few months they may try some other attack.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I also find the word **even** a bit strange in legal context. Had it been a letter from one friend trying to convince another friend of something then they might use that word in this sentence; but in a legal document they would state facts and not “persuasive text”.

Comment: I like this answer because it only requires an investigation of the e-mail. I concur pressuring immediate action before _other people_ do it first is an immediate red flag. It is a common pattern in scams.

Comment: I think they are referring to a [Squeeze out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze-out).  The Wikipedia page doesn't tell specifics about the US (just "there are state specific rules"), but in general it won't be "without any compensation".

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Hmm... I wonder if it possibly could happen without compensation in this case, due to the company being bankrupt (and, thus, probably having a stock value of $0.)

Comment: @reirab But the "lawyer" has just sent a letter indicating that the company does have assets worth controlling. I'm not a lawyer but I feel like this would be a really stupid idea if you were then planning to claim that the fair value was zero.

Comment: @ssn Agreed. Nothing in the letter reads like proper lawyer-speak; I highlighted a few of the more blatant issues, but even without any of the points I mentioned, the general style would make me very suspicious.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent True.

Comment: In addition in the US there is no 'receivership'; the word we use is 'bankruptcy'. (The entity put in control of a bankupt's estate is a 'trustee'.) Although bankrupt shares (generally) cannot be listed and trade on an _exchange_, they usually still trade in the 'over-the-counter' _market_. And they definitely still have 'corporate IDs' (CUSIP, SEC CIK, EIN for tax in addition to any id from the chartering state) although _if_ they were on an exchange, which a closed-end trust may not be to start with, they do lose the ticker for that exchange.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent When you quote `I will put you in the payout list.`, you could also see this `I will`. The guy that sent you the email will do it? Not a chance this will happen. No one would use the first person in this case (in a legal case).

Comment: One other point: It is incongruous to suggest that the company has "assets" which are worth controlling while it is simultaneously bankrupt and without an executive board.  You can't have it both ways.  If they mean chapter 7 liquidation, then the company's liabilities exceed its assets and it's not worth buying an extra 25% stake even for pennies per share.  If they mean chapter 11 reorganization, then the company most certainly does have an executive board which can be contacted.

Answer (score 18):

> In case I provide my bank account number (IBAN number in the EU), how will they be able to abuse this?

There are multiple ways. In this case, it could be that once you give the details, they will mention that you need to pay something [lawyer fees, capital gains tax, other such items] before they release the funds to you. Further threatening you about trying to evade something / doing something illegal and ask for more money. They may even initiate a transfer [that can be retracted later] for a large amount and ask you to refund as they send this amount in error ... etc.

> What are they trying to do with me signing the PSPA / PSA documents?

Could be nothing, just trying to give it an air of credibility. Or could be they are trying to corner max shares at zero costs ... with the possibility that the company when it comes out of bankruptcy they will make an handsome gain.

Comment: I'm also interested in why in particular they want the "documents"; and why in particular they want the bank account info.  My first guess would be simply the usual "you have to send us a small fee first"...  But I don't know.

Comment: @Fattie that's exactly what is puzzling me: they want the bank account number to liquidate my investment - to pay me! Or so they say, of course. That's exactly what I am trying to understand.

Comment: I totally understand and I too want to know!  I want to know how they got the list, whether it's just "that company's" list or they have many; and also what their goals are.

Comment: @Fattie they got at least my phone number right, and the fact that I was an investor in the company, so yes, they have some kind of list. I thought that maybe an employee with access to the company investor details sold that information in the market, or even started a scam operation. Maybe this is a common procedure with companies in liquidation, to further extort former investors?

Comment: @Fattie you know what, I am re-reading the exchange via email, and I start to think that they *did not* get the name of the company right: it was probably *me* (!) who gave them that information. In the official documents they only use the dummy "Natural Resource Investment Trust" name, and not the real name of the company I invested in and went bankrupt. In the email exchange they do mention Greenwood, which is actually completely wrong: the company going bankrupt was Greenleaf, and Greenwood is the name of a completely different company which is **not** bankrupt.

Comment: It seems the procedure is: call random investors telling them of a badly gone investment which can be salvaged, gather as much information as possible, sound legitimate, and collect more real data from said investors, including signatures and bank account numbers. Not yet sure what is the final goal, but this seems to be the procedure.

Comment: fascinating, @dangonfast !!

Comment: @Fattie if they have your bank information, signature, and other personal data, they've effectively succeeded at getting everything they need to control that bank account in many countries. So they can empty out the bank account, and probably do more to stop you recovering it as well.

Comment: See this answer . They can access your bank account with your signature in Germany at least https://money.stackexchange.com/a/15237/63585

Comment: They probably hacked the email account of someone indirectly involved with your investments, and are trying to get access to yours and others funds. I believe you should contact the police.

Comment: how would the "They may even initiate a transfer [that can be retracted later] for a large amount and ask you to refund as they send this amount in error" work in europe? what prevents you from keeping that cash? if i ever see random 0's added to my account by "Kenyan Princes In need LTD" my first action will be close it & transfer to a new one, it's a 5 min procedure to avoid scams here.

Comment: @CptEric Transfering the funds and closing the account does not mean your liability ends. The bank can open the account, apply the reversal, start charging for overdraft and chase you initially and then via court if they want to; depending on amounts involved. They can even report to authorities that you are part of Money Laundering syndicate.

Comment: @Dheer unless you previously inform the bank you're a victim of a scam and that's the reason you're closing the account. my bank has quite tight deadlines on those procedures and it's very straightforward.

Answer (score 13):

This sounds like a scam, how really depends on the paperwork they want you to sign. Here is an additional piece that is cause for concern:

I did a reverse imagesearch on their [about picture](http://www.burkecorporatelaw.com/image/about1.jpg)  and it is a placeholder. Now there might be a reason to choose a placeholder instead of showing your partners but its at the very least unusual.

Also searching for them [here](http://member.vsb.org/attsearch/search.aspx) did not yield any results. Granted it explicitly says that not all members are listed but the offer assistance finding a member

> If you have trouble locating a member, please call us for assistance at (804)775-0530 or send an email to membership@vsb.org

Comment: @other_paul, that is fascinating about the placeholder!   Note too - overwhelmingly, **every single legal practice must and does list all the partners and senior staff**.  So the site is just a total non-starter.

Answer (score 11):

Whether you *think* it is a scam has nothing to do with reality.   People too easily convince themselves of things they want to believe -- a scam is a *confidence* game which revolves around making you want to believe.

- The message should be presumed to be fraudulent.

*Mind you, I treat exactly the same way every "latest things on Netflix" email, I would **never** click on any link in it and then log in.* It is, at best, a "teaser" to encourage you to start independent action.

- All contact info in the email should be considered fraudulent.

Don't you dare reply to the email or call the phone number listed in the email!  Even if the domain is real, the email server is compromised. The number goes to a "Vumber" or free Google Voice number. The street address will be bona-fide, but that's only to add to the appearance of legitimacy. They don't expect you to physically visit.

- Independently investigate the message found in the email, *without using any resources from it*.

In this case, you start by searching public information. Who is the bankruptcy receiver? Look in reputable newspapers and the like, e.g. Washingtonpost.com. Beware fake news created by the scammer.

If that just doesn't work, you can try searching for the law firm named in the email.  However be careful to authenticate that they are a serious, going concern firm, not a fake law firm created by the scammer.

Look up the law firm's official web site -- choose organic search results, not advertisements which the scammer could have bought -- and call the number on the official web site.

It may be that all the info in the email checks out. It's true, non-fraudulent emails have happened.   In that case, **don't feel stupid, feel thorough**.

By calling, you will get more attention, which may help your place in line.  If it's real.   Asking for your bank details so early in process seems super dodgy.

Comment: All very sound advice.

Answer (score 9):

Similar to the reverse search of the image mentioned by @other_paul, a useful check for plagiarism is to find an 'unusual phrase' and see if it appears elsewhere.

For example, I took "caring about a client's cost restraints" from their [about us page](http://www.burkecorporatelaw.com/about-us.php) (I'd expect 'constraints' instead of 'restraints').

Using that phrase (including the quotes) in a google search reveals both the [apparent source of the text](https://globalphiladelphia.org/businesses/morgan-lewis-bockius) (a practice in Philadelphia) and, more usefully, [a warning about a now-defunct scam site](https://www.scamwarners.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&p=299985) using the same text and similar email footer.

As everyone seems to agree- almost certainly a scam.

Answer (score 9):

> The remaining 25% would be immediately absorbed by the new owner and
>   have no financial value whatsoever to the existing shareholder. Under
>   US law this is perfectly legal and a commonly used practice of
>   acquiring full control through the purchase of a majority interest.

I'm not a lawyer, but I am certain that this is *not* perfectly legal and *not* a practice of acquiring full control.

The stock you own is an actual part of the company, and if another company is buying the company then they are legally obligated to buy your stock from you.  I've had a situation where a company I had stock in approved being bought out by another company, and a per-share price was agreed upon for purchase of the company.  All stockholders then received as payment the agreed upon price times the number of shares they held in the company.  I had no control over the fact that the merger happened (well, a little, but I didn't own nearly enough shared to change the vote approving the merger), but everybody got paid.

Comment: indeed, the only time shareholders would not get paid is if the company went into receivership and there wasn't enough left in the holdings after paying off taxes and banks (and some others maybe depending on jurisdiction) to make payments to other stakeholders (like shareholders, employees, suppliers). And in that case the percentage of shares you own is irrelevant.

Comment: Why not simply make it so that when company A acquires company B, all company B stock becomes company A stock, without having to buy out all of company B's stockholders?

Comment: @Sean, this would be more of a merger than a buyout.

Comment: @Joshua: My question still stands.

Comment: @Sean, I don't have an answer to "why".  I think your question merits its own ask on this site though.

Answer (score 5):

I won't repeat JoeTaxpayer's research. That sounds very interesting and informative.

But I'll add several red flags from the text of the email.

"he already has 51% control of of the common shares, however, it is his intention to acquire at least 75% of the outstanding shares to gain complete control" Why would he need 75% to "gain complete control"? Why isn't 51% enough? Maybe there's some government regulation I'm not familiar with, but this sounds unlikely.

"The remaining 25% would be immediately absorbed by the new owner and have no financial value whatsoever to the existing shareholder." How would that be true? There are all sorts of laws in the US to protect the interests of minority shareholders. I'm not a securities lawyer, but I find it hard to believe that they would leave this gaping loophole. This sounds more like the classic sales tactic of pressuring the customer that he has to buy today or the deal will go away. Once our client gets 75%, all remaining stock will be worthless. If you don't act RIGHT NOW, you could be left out in the cold.

"Under US law this is perfectly legal" People who are doing something that is perfectly legal rarely find it necessary to tell others that what they are doing is perfectly legal. (Unless someone questions it.) When someone assures me that the product he is trying to sell me is completely legal, I figure there are two likely possibilities: (a) It is not legal, he knows that it sounds fishy, and he's trying to overcome my obvious suspicion; or (b) He wants me to think that it is just barely legal and I better get in on it before the government cracks down. When was the last time that you wrote a business memo where you found it necessary to say, "what I'm suggesting is completely legal"?

"There is no administrative board to contact, and it doesn't even have a valid corporate ID any more, therefore research options are very limited,as you can imagine." That is, there's no way for you to check if we're telling you the truth, so don't even bother to try. That sentence by itself sounds super suspicious. Note to self: If I ever try to perpetrate a scam, encourage the victims to check out the facts for themselves. The careful ones would do this anyway, and by sounding open and honest I may trick a number of people into thinking, "Well, if he's not worried about me checking him out, obviously he has nothing to hide", and maybe I'll trick them into NOT checking.

"This is a first come first served situation ,so obviously time is of the essence." Act now! While supplies last! Limited time offer! A sure sign of a scam. You can't afford to take the time to check this out -- if you do you may miss your chance!

One other little thing I noticed. On the Burke website, under their description of their practice areas, they say:

"Mergers & Acquisitions: Burke Corporate Law is a global leader among firms involved in mergers and acquisitions and other corporate transactions. The transactional experience of Burke Corporate Law ’s lawyers have allowed us to maintain our leadership position, representing a broad array of public and private companies, private equity firms, governmental entities, and other institutions and individuals in every type of M&A situation."

In a quick search I found another law firm called Skadden that says:

"Mergers & Acquisitions: Skadden is a global leader among law firms involved in mergers and acquisitions and other corporate transactions. The transactional experience of Skadden’s lawyers, the breadth of our practice and the geographical reach of our offices worldwide have allowed us to maintain our leadership position, representing a broad array of public and private companies, private equity firms and financial sponsors, investment banks, governmental entities, and other institutions and individuals in almost every type of M&A situation."

Skadden's description of their Private Equity practice was also word-for-word identical, except for substituting company name, for about half the text. Then it diverged, not sure what to make of that.

Maybe Burke copied their descriptions from Skadden, or maybe this is standard boilerplate text used by a hundred law firms. Either way, subtracts from credibility.

As JoeTaxpayer or someone said, the web site is only a few months old. So it might be that this is a new law firm and they just haven't had time to get a good website together yet. Or it could be that it's a scam and they threw together a quick web site. In fairness, the web site is much more elaborate than most scam web sites I've seen. Usually scammers just have a page or two.

Comment: 75% sounds very reasonable to me.  In England and Wales, many resolutions at a company general meeting (AGM or EGM) only require a simple majority (50%+1), however some resolutions are categorized as "special resolutions", and require 75% to pass.  In particular, a special resolution can *force* shareholders to sell to a buyer.  It wouldn't surprise me to find that some (all?) US states have similar rules.

Comment: ... but you are right that the remain 25% will get the agreed price.

Answer (score 2):

I will dissent from the other answers here and say that this might be legitimate.  If you actually bought these shares and the correspondence you received mentions those shares and it was sent to your correct address, that lends legitimacy to it because unless someone hacked a brokerage or stock clearing house or something they would not know that you owned those shares.  A spammer would not send out millions of spam messages mentioning a single stock hoping that they happen to find a shareholder.

Companies do contact their shareholders occasionally and this has happened to me.  For example I owned 50 shares of a stock that I had completely forgotten about.  I think I got a stock certificate made for one of my kids and forgot about it. The company went through a reverse stock split and there were fractional shares which had to be paid in cash.  I got a correspondence somewhat like what you received in the mail telling me to contact them about the stock, and when I did, they gave me the information I needed to access my shares.

I have also owned stock in a company that went bankrupt and as part of the bankruptcy process the lawyers sent correspondence to all shareholders to let them know what was happening, basically tell them that their investment was legally worthless, but this was a necessary step in settling the accounts in bankruptcy.

When you open a brokerage account or other account you can use to own stock (DRIP etc) you have to provide a physical address, and this goes on record with your stock holdings.  If for example your broker went out of business, you still own those shares and the stock clearing house keeps track of who owns what.

As far as the 51% / 75% claim, I am familiar with this as well.  The percentage of shares of a class of stock that you need to have control can vary, it is often 51% but can be higher or lower, and this can vary with different types of stock (common, preferred, restricted, etc).  It can also vary by what type of corporate action they want to enact.  A simple vote may require a 51% majority but a special resolution may require 75%.  Special resolutions are needed for major corporate changes such as a name change, creating or retiring a class of stock, stock capitalization changes, etc.

Often when a publicly traded company goes bankrupt, the company may halt operations but the shell of the publicly traded company still exists and is registered with the SEC and has done the other legal things that are needed to be a public company.  This shell company can be valuable for a small private company that wants to become publicly traded but is not yet, it is basically a back door way of going public on the cheap.  There are even holders and brokers of public shell companies that will sell them to companies who are trying to go public.  Doing a transaction like this usually requires a name change and other corporate actions that require a special resolution and 75% of the shareholder vote.

This is a common source of these special resolutions, companies usually have thousands of shareholders and if you had say 65% of the votes needed for a resolution, you need to round up another 10% of shareholders to get them to comply and what you would do is send correspondence exactly like what you received to the shareholders of record.

So with all of this said, I think that the situation in the correspondence is plausible.  I am not a lawyer but I am a registered investment advisor and have been investing in the public markets for over 20 years.  However if you don't want to take my word for any of this please Google some of these terms such as "75% special resolution", "public shell company", "stock clearing house", etc.  You can also go to the SEC's Free Edgar web site and look up the SEC filings for the company, where you should see public filings describing whatever reorganization they're working on.

If you do follow up on this I would use common sense ways of avoiding being drawn into a scam.  Verify any email address or phone number that you call independently.  Remember that if you call anyone they will immediately get your phone number and rough geographic location from caller ID.  You mentioned Burke Corporate Law, it is easy to independently verify if that company actually exists (call the bar association if you really want to be sure) and you can call their main number rather than any other number you've been given.  Don't give any personal information such as your SSN, date of birth or address over the phone until you've become certain that you're talking to someone legitimate, etc.  Don't give your bank account or credit card information to someone so they can make a deposit on your behalf or anything like that, this is a common scam.  If you own something you should be able to call some customer service number and arrange to have your shares transferred somewhere else.

Comment: This answer ignores the web site and the lack of names on it. Also, hacking happens all the time, and then the information is sold/shared on the darkweb, so I don't find that argument compelling either. And then, there is the fact that this information came over email. A law firm would have probably used your mailing address and sent an actual letter by international post to establish initial contact (not that actual letters can't be scams too, but they actually show more effort and look more serious).

Comment: Yes I agree that this is somewhat suspicious.  I am guessing the lawyer, or supposed lawyer, is using corporate hoteling space and a cell phone, which doesn't bode well for legitimacy.  However the other objections that were raised in this thread, the company being bankrupt, contacting its shareholders, 50% vs. 75% ownership, etc. are all fairly common.